# Calculating a probability using the join density function

Tags: probability, density-function

here's the problem I'm currently working on :

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variable with join density function given by $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-x^2y}1_{[1,\infty)}(x)1_{[0,\infty)}(y). $$

Since $e^{x}>0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that  $f_{X,Y}>0, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Also we see that

\begin{align*}
\int \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy &=\int_{1}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2y} dy \right) dx\\
                     &=\int_{1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{-1}{x^2}e^{-x^2y} \right]_{0}^{\infty}dx\\
                     &=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}dx\\
                     &=\left[ \frac{-1}{x} \right]_{1}^{\infty}\\
                     &=1.
\end{align*}

Therefore, we know that $f_{X,Y}$ is a density function and we can move on to the next question. It is asked to evaluate the folowing probabilty : $\mathbb{P}(X^2Y>1)$.

I am unsure how to find the right boundaries for the integrals. Here's what I've done so far :

The condition $X^2Y>1$ gives us the following inequalities :

$$1 \leq x < \infty \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} \frac{1}{x^2} \leq y < \infty$$

or

$$0 \leq y < \infty \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \leq x < \infty.$$

From that I deduce the two folowing double integrals :

$$ \mathbb{P}(X^2Y>1)=\int_{1}^{\infty} \left( \int_{x^{-2}}^{\infty} e^{-x^2y}dy \right)dx $$

and

$$ \mathbb{P}(X^2Y>1)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \int_{y^{-1/2}}^{\infty} e^{-x^2y}dx \right)dy. $$

I already evaluated the first integral but the second one is more complicated. I am right ? How do you find the boundaries for such problems ?

Thanks

Comment: The second integral does not take into account that $1 \leq x$ (and allows $x < 1$)

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. Do you mean that because $y$ can take values in $[0,1)$ ? Should I also add the condition : $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \geq 1$?

Comment: That still does not work because then you are limiting the $y$ values to $y \leq 1$. There is no simple way to do the second integral. If you want to do it that way, you need to break the integral into two parts by looking at the region $x^2y > 1$ for $1 \leq x$.

Comment: thanks, it's all clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first integral is correct and gives you the right solution:

$$\mathbb{P}[X^2Y>1]=\frac{1}{e}$$

the second one is wrong

The correct one should be

$$\mathbb{P}[X^2Y>1]=\int_0^{1}\Bigg[\int_{y^{-\frac{1}{2}}}^{\infty}e^{-x^2y}dx   \Bigg]dy+\int_1^{\infty}\Bigg[\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x^2y}dx   \Bigg]dy$$

It is self evident that it is better the first choice.

**This is a clear example showing that not always integration's order is neutral.**

---

The requested probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[X^2Y>1]=\mathbb{P}[Y>\frac{1}{X^2}]$$

Thus the area to be integrated is the following purple one (the blu curve is the equation $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$)

[image]

In your second way to solve it you tried to integrate also the yellow one

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Unfortunately I don't understand how you get your answer. How did you figure out what to write in the "inside" integral ? Thanks again

Comment: @Alain See my edits

Comment: Thank you again for your kind help. I just understood my mistake. I just needed to flip the graph to correctly see how to integrate. Thanks a lot !
May Iask you how you produced this graph in LaTex ?